# Babel jest isn't working with loaded css module

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I get the following error when running a simple component test with jest.

```
FAIL  src/components/header/Header.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Volumes/WorkSpace/Projects/wc2/src/components/header/Header.scss:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){@import "../../styles/variables";
                                                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../../../Users/micahblu/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/je
st-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/header/Header.tsx:2:1)
```

The  component imports a header.scss. The original error complained about the @import statement I had at the beginning of the file, but even removing that it complains about the '.' in the beginning of a css class declaration. It apparently doesn't work at all with css? or scss? I have all the proper babel loaders for css and sass and they work fine in development, I would assume babel-jest should understand how to handle the file.

in my package.json I have:

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(tsx|ts)?$": "typescript-babel-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "json"
    ]
  }
```

Header.test.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import Header from './Header'

test('output', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(<Header />)
  expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Header.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-redux-router'
import "./Header.scss"

const Header = () => (
    <header>
        <h1>My header</h1>
    </header>
)

export default Header
```

Header.scss

```
@import "../../styles/variables";

header {
  background: white
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `moduleNameMapper` property to replace any static assets with mocks.

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(tsx|ts)?$": "typescript-babel-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^.+\\.scss$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "json"
    ]
}
```

Here is the documentation: [Jest Documentation - Static Assets](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html#handling-static-assets)

Use the identity-obj-proxy as the mock, which can be installed by `npm install --save-dev identity-obj-proxy`.